# Integrating an application in the windows shell?

Tags: c#, windows, file, user-interface, shell

I am creating a file-sharing application I want to integrate into a windows shell. I am writing the core in portable C but the windows GUI in C#.

What I want to achieve is to for example add custom selection/option when you right-click a file (like, WinRAR adds custom option when you right-click a file, it allows you to rar the file and whatnot). I am not sure what the term is called though.

How do you do this in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for a *shell extension* for the *context menu*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about something called a "shell extension". There are degrees of complexity associated with doing this sort of thing, as with everything. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx) is a good starting point and example; searching Google for "C# shell extension" returns lots of useful links.

Comment: i can't find that many articles about it; they all keep refering to it being bad in C#

Comment: Actually, so long as you use .net 4.0, the problems with C# shell extensions no longer arise. That said, it seems a bit much spinning up a .net 4.0 runtime just to handle a couple of context menu items. I'd do it in native code myself.

Comment: Do you know any good resource for native? Is it much less work than C#? (ATL or MFC I do not like, but pure c++ is fine)

Comment: It won't be the fastest shell extension in the world, but it will probably be easier and faster than C++/ATL.